# How to create a cron job to run every 30 days in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I am trying to write a cron job using [cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) to run every 30 days.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? like `0 0 */30 * * <command> <path/to/your/script>` ? It took me less than a minute to find on google

Comment: Have you checked: https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron

Comment: Here is a tutorial how to setup cronjobs [cron at ubuntuusers](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/cron).

Comment: Thanks @JonathanBrooks...

Answer (score 1):

Using [cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) this is how i was able to solve it... Thanks to @Jonathan Brooks

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob({
  cronTime: '00 00 00 28,29,30 * *',
  onTick: function() {
    console.log('Runs every 28, 29(february) or 30 days');
  },
  start: true,
  timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
});
```